# Представления SQL

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо создать представление, отображающее количество арендованных жилых и нежилых объектов недвижимости физическими и юридическими лицами каждый месяц текущего года.

Comment: В чем вопрос? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Отсутствует понимание, как выделить отчеты по месяцам, то есть результат должен выглядить так:
месяц кол-во юр.лиц кол-во физлиц. кол-во жилых площадей.
Как отдельно выделить месяца и все это в один запрос.

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе следует использовать функции агрегирования.
Как это сделать, лучше почитай доку - поймешь намного лучше, если сам в этом разберёшься.

- [GROUP BY оператор](http://oracleplsql.ru/group-by.html)
- [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007434)

А как напишешь правильный запрос - засунуть его во view не составит проблем.